# RichTextBlock overflow is missing the first line of text

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, richtextblock, richtextblockoverflow

I've got a `Grid` that is dynamically sized based on the size of the window it is in. The grid has three children: an `Image`, a `RichTextBlock`, and a `RichTextBlockOverflow`. When the window is sized down enough to ensure that the height of the `RichTextBlock` becomes 0, the overflow content does not include the first line (which the `RichTextBlock` couldn't *visibly* render.

In the sample code below (reduced to just show the essentials), I only see "World" in my overflow.

```
<Grid MinHeight="200" MinWidth="400">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image />
    <RichTextBlock x:Name="Text" Grid.Row="1" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=OverflowText}">
        <Paragraph>Hello<LineBreak />World</Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
    <RichTextBlockOverflow Name="OverflowText" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Is there any way to ensure that the overflow would have all the text in case the RichTextBlock doesn't have enough space to render the first line?

Comment: Does RT not have `OverflowContentTarget`? If so you might set `OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=OverflowText}"` on your RichTextBlock, I'd have to test to confirm but seems like a nuance worth checking.

Comment: @ChrisW. It does, and that's what I was using. Sorry I accidentally removed that when I was copy-pasting my XAML.